# splitting cued audio files in command line with xld on osx

Tags: bash, macos, unix, ape

I'm writing a script for batch processing audio files, with xld. I want to find unsplitted albums, split them and convert them in flac, with the proper tags.

```
find . -name "*.ape" -exec sh -c 'exec xld  "$1" -f flac' _ {} \;
```

this command line is converting the audio to flac but i have to add "-c filename.cue" option with xld to make it split the file.

> find . -name "*.ape" -exec sh -c 'exec echo $1 | sed 's/.ape/.cue/'' _
> {} ;

this command line shows me the path of .cue files

> find . -name "*.ape" -exec sh -c 'exec xld  "$1" -f flac -c $1 | sed
> 's/.ape/.cue/'' _ {} ;

this command line doesn't work, xld says he didn't found de cue file. i think it's just a syntax problem.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not at a computer to test this like I normally would, but in `bash` you can substitute the trailing part of a variable like this:

```
thing="fred.ape"
echo ${thing/%.ape/.cue}
fred.cue
```

It's called *"parameter substitution/expansion"* and is explained with examples [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

So, based on that, you'd need to exec `bash` something like this:

```
find . -name "*.ape" -exec bash -c "xld  "$1" -f flac -c "${1/%.ape/.cue}"' _ {} \;
```

---

Personally, I'd do them all in parallel with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel xld {} -f flac -c {.}.cue ::: *.ape
```

You can install it with **homebrew** using:

```
brew install parallel
```